# How to display form data onclick of submit button in html page without using Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Iam developing a Jquery Mobile app - Song Lyrics which is having a single page index.html where I have manually added few songs in List view. Now I want to add new Song Lyrics which must be displayed in List view. I have a form where user fills : Song name,Lyricist name & song Lyrics. I don't want to use Database. so now my question is how to store the form Data & display it in List view. Is there any way to save the Dynamic form data in some .txt file & display it on html page or any other way, I have tried so may ways but could not find solution. 
Please help thank you.
Here is my Code index.html Page

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mobile App using Jquery</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-G0fIWCsCzJIMAVNQPfjH08cyYaUtMwjJwqiRKxxE/rx96Uroj1BtIQ6MLJuheaO9" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <style>
 .fullscreen{
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
 }
 h1{
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #E76C67;
    margin-top: 0%;
 }
 h2{
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #444444;
    margin-top: -3%;
 }
 </style>
  </head>
<body>
<!--Index Page startes Here --> 


<div data-role="page" id="demo-page" data-url="demo-page">
    <div data-role="header">
          <h1>Gospel Songs </h1>
            <a href="#" id="home" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"> Home</a>

        <a href="#" class="jqm-search-link ui-shadow ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-icon-search ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-btn-right">Search</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" id="sortedList" data-filter="true">
             <li><a href="#"><h1>All The Way My Saviour Leads Me lyrics</h1>
    <p>All the way my Savior leads me
What have I to ask beside?....
</p>
   <a href="#A1"> </a>
    </a>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#"><h1>Amazing Grace lyrics</h1>
    <p>"Amazing Grace, how sweet the sound,...</p>
    <a href="#A2" > </a>
    </a>
     </li>

            <li><a href="#"><h1><span id='display_song_name'></span> </h1> </a></li>
        </ul><!-- /listview -->
    </div><!-- /content -->
<footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"> 
  <nav data-role="navbar">     
   <ul>    
    <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="home"> Home </a></li>
 <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="grid">Photos</a></li>
 <li><a href="#add_song" data-icon="plus" data-transition="flip" id="#add_song"> Add Song </a> </li>
   </ul>  
  </nav>

</footer><!-- /footer -->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="add_song">
     <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Add Songs Lyrics</h1>
            <a href="index.html" id="home" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"> Home</a>
   
     </div>
      <div role="main" class="ui-contain">
   <form id="myform" type="post">
       <label for="basic">Song Name:</label>
       <input type="text" name="name" id="song_name" value="">
    <label for="basic">lyricist Name:</label>
       <input type="text" name="name" id="lyricist_name" value="">
    <label for="textarea">Song Lyrics:</label>
       <textarea name="song_lyrics" id="song_lyrics"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
     </div>
<footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"> 
  <nav data-role="navbar">     
   <ul>    
    <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="home"> Home </a></li>
 <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="grid">Photos</a></li>
 <li><a href="" data-icon="plus" id="add_song"> Add Song </a> </li>
   </ul>  
  </nav>
</footer><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- ADD_SONG_PAGE content -->





</body>
</html>
```

I have a button in footer: Add Song when user click on button it takes us to new page: opens form.

Comment: You've simply described a Web page. Mobile apps would be developed in Java for Android or Objective-C for iPhone etc.

Comment: Iam developing Mobile app using Jquery.

Comment: This should clear the terminology up: https://www.hswsolutions.com/services/mobile-web-development/mobile-website-vs-apps/A mobile website is similar to any other website in that it consists of browser-based HTML pages that are linked together and accessed over the Internet (for mobile typically WiFi or 3G or 4G networks).

Comment: Apps are actual applications that are downloaded and installed on your mobile device, rather than being rendered within a browser. Users visit device-specific portals such as  Apple’s App Store, Android Market, or Blackberry App World in order to find and download apps for a given operating system. The app may pull content and data from the Internet, in similar fashion to a website, or it may download the content so that it can be accessed without an Internet connection

Answer (score 0):

You added the tag `HTML5` so you can use webstorage, take a look: http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webstorage.asp.

From W3Schools:

> With web storage, web applications can store data locally within the
>   user's browser.
>
> Before HTML5, application data had to be stored in cookies, included
>   in every server request. Web storage is more secure, and large amounts
>   of data can be stored locally, without affecting website performance.
>
> Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and
>   information is never transferred to the server.
>
> Web storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from
>   one origin, can store and access the same data.

Comment: I have tried to use Local storage, it saves the data however as soon as I enter next field it replaces with the earlier content.

Comment: In that case put your code using local storage so we can check it